# Making multiple changes to one JSON template

Tags: json, bash, templates, jq

I'm currently using `jq` with the 1pass CLI to try and create randomly generated passwords into a secure note. I'm having an issue with setting the fields.

These are two of my variables. I have 8 total I need to set.

```
section0_section_uuid="Section_0"

section1_section_uuid="Section_1"
```

And here are my commands to manipulate the template. I first read it in, change the first title,  then save it to `$template`. I then pass `$template` into `jq`

```
template=$(cat template.json | jq --arg uuid "$section0_section_uuid" '.sections[0].title=$uuid')

template=$($template | jq --arg uuid "$section1_section_uuid" '.sections[1].title=$uuid')

echo $template
```

I get "file name too long." I don't think I'm passing the modified template variable in correctly. I need to do 7 more modifications to the `template.json` file.

Edit:

Here's the full template I'm trying to manipulate. It's 12 total changes to the template I have to make. 10 of the 12 are random numbers that I will generate. The remaining 2 of the 12 will be a generated usernames.

```
{
  "fields": [],
  "sections": [
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "ROOT_USER_PASS",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME]"
        },
        {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "DEV_USER_PASS",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME]"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Section_[CHANGE_ME]",
      "title": "Container SSH"
    },
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "k": "string",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "placeholdertext",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME_LETTERS]"
        },
        {
          "k": "string",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "placeholdertext",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME_LETTERS]"
        },
        {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "placeholdertext",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME]"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Section_[CHANGE_ME]",
      "title": "MySQL"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In the second command, you are _not_ echoing the value of `template`, add an `echo` before `$template`

Comment: There could be better suggestions than running the command each time, provide your input json and state the expected output. It will be easy to suggest alternate solutions

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm not that experienced with bash. I thought the $() wrapping made it return, so I wouldn't need to echo it back.

Answer (score 12):

Why not make your template an actual `jq` filter, rather than a JSON blob to modify?

The contents of `template.jq` would be

```
{
  sections: [
    { title: $t1 },
    { title: $t2 },
    { title: $t3 },
    { title: $t4 },
    { title: $t5 },
    { title: $t6 },
    { title: $t7 },
    { title: $t8 }
  ]
}
```

Then your command would simply be

```
$ jq -n --arg t1 foo --arg t2 bar ... -f template.jq
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "foo"
    },
    {
      "title": "bar"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

One benefit of doing it this way is that you can't accidentally forget a value; `jq` can only process the filter if you provide definitions for all 8 variables.

Comment: Rather than defining N arguments for each of the new names, it would be easier to create an array of the new titles and update the titles for the corresponding sections. Then it's just a matter of looping through the titles and sections and setting the titles.

Comment: An array in shell, or an array in `jq`? I considered the latter, but didn't really put the time in to implement it cleanly.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I made a file called template.jq, copied your template over to it. I then ran your code, substituting foo and bar in for different values, and it gives:

error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'{

Doesn't seem to like your template file.

Comment: My mistake; I didn't delete the last comma in the `sections` list after copy-and-pasting to build it.

Comment: Very helpful.  Is it possible to append text to the var in the template?  "${t1}suffix" in quotes doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses jq to build a legal json array from bash variables and then uses that array with a second jq invocation to substitute the variables into the template at corresponding positions:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# example template
template='{
  "sections": [
    { "title": "x" },
    { "title": "y" }
  ]
}'

# bash variables 
section0_section_uuid="Section_0"
section1_section_uuid="Section_1"

# put into json array with jq
uuids=$(jq -MRn '[inputs]' <<EOF
$section0_section_uuid
$section1_section_uuid
EOF)

# substitute json array into template
jq -M --argjson uuids "$uuids" '
  reduce ($uuids|keys[]) as $k (.; .sections[$k].title = $uuids[$k])
' <<< "$template"
```

Sample Output

```bash
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "Section_0"
    },
    {
      "title": "Section_1"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBRT4MwFIXf@yuOHQmQCNteFR71zZjoIyFL2RpXwLLRoiNzvx3bDpYZ9an3npze795TMLUdhtnNvBByXpiGkBn4gb3vag7NzcM0J1OR@kcCUMXXWjRS0TtkpgeOoFromhuBHihOt7/U3qhGzMnJtwRLwgdrBStqrkDGiYvVWKy6TmxS@jp2Czo5lv84ltSO3XUaQuoGpWokWNuyHp9Cb1HuifWr1AvKPaKnFwk/E9L4Ve4jSR6eH4n35xIX@SeZmB@hRaquUObKTvNrqFviEp9DIopY@@Y8bhVQz70Uvgmm5ZtuzRGcta@K9yrLQzAFr0IQ3yOeQs@8Ko9drkhxtlspJPaOxEydsHQYvgE)

---

Here is a solution to a portion of the revised problem which works by replacing leaf values in the template with corresponding values from an object constructed from bash variables and passed to jq via `--argjson`.  It should be straightforward to generalize to the complete template assuming more suitable names are chosen for replacement values then `[CHANGE_ME]` and `[CHANGE_ME_LETTERS]`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# example template
template='{
  "fields": [],
  "sections": [ {
      "fields": [ {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "[SSH_ROOT_USER_N]",
          "t": "ROOT_USER_PASS",
          "v": "[SSH_ROOT_USER_V]"
      } ]
  } ]
}'

# bash variables 
SSH_ROOT_USER_N="abcd"
SSH_ROOT_USER_V="efgh"

# put into json object with jq
vars=$(jq -M . <<EOF
{
 "[SSH_ROOT_USER_N]": "$SSH_ROOT_USER_N",
 "[SSH_ROOT_USER_V]": "$SSH_ROOT_USER_V"
}
EOF)

# substitute variables into template
jq -M --argjson vars "$vars" '
reduce (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (
    {}
  ; setpath($p;if $v|type!="string" then . else $vars[$v]//$v end)
)
' <<< "$template"
```

Sample Output

```bash
{
  "fields": {},
  "sections": [
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "abcd",
          "t": "ROOT_USER_PASS",
          "v": "efgh"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBTsJAFLzvVzzWJrQJSOJR6MGDxotiqHIhDdm2D7pYt6X7qBLg2@tuEUSkh77uvMnszDQSOq3rq1YvkqoXmQNjV4Bf4qPIEAjNEITs8OG3NwyAzyRmiea3MAk79qwxJpmrBgHLsM8J64g1@LuBeJyrGEWGCe@c7pTdTYLgcToaDl@nb8H9aPoc/uWQ5fyuX@6C4C@huiAyDvkPZQch2793bRvWhoZKlFJEGWpgZ5f7XERxws/gsc9xNk@5FShWBFJRDgudK8ijhWkDPiWlsFgyI6x9x10sofsE1zAY3A8fmKnjQkhj2jkDba4LSf4zx5ztmJH2rCG9ijRJWhHuLYmyFOu9xeMf3RvqdkU5bzjWp1G1g0OblZisYgSXck0lio@txszEcjNUc0p9/8bzQGiYOEXHqUJwm243OzP6oJEKQanrFH05A6fa0rrAls@NklRzDpSiMlVgphGaCydGotdzKkCVeMxjbVPTwJg5mOWsrr8B)

Comment: Great answer! but I wasn't super clear in my original question. It's not as uniformed as adding in 10 different section titles. I included the template that I'm actually working with. There's an array inside section that holds objects of values.

Comment: I've added a more general solution which should work provided you can choose meaningful names for the variables to be substituted.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach to the problem is similar to @jq170727's (in particular, the jq program is agnostic both about the *number* of "section_uuid" variables, and the *names* of the template variables), but only one invocation of jq is required (rather than three).

The other significant difference is that `reduce` is used to avoid the penalties associated with using `tostream`.  A minor difference is that `inputs` is used to avoid reading in the "section_uuid" variable values all at once.

> ***Note: The `fillin` function defined below should be sufficient for basic templating.***

In the following, the "template" file is assumed to be named `template.json`.

#### template.jq

```
# input: a JSON entity defining a template;
# vars: a JSON object defining TEMPLATEVARIABLE-VALUE pairs
def fillin(vars):
  reduce paths as $p (.;
    getpath($p) as $v
    | if $v|type == "string" and vars[$v] 
      then setpath($p; vars[$v])
      else . 
      end);

reduce inputs as $line ({i:0, value:$template};
  (.value.sections[.i].title |= $line)
  | .i +=1)
| .value
| fillin($vars)
```

#### The script

```
#!/bin/bash

### Set the bash variables - as many as needed

section0_section_uuid="Section_0"
section1_section_uuid="Section_1"

ROOT_USER_PASS=RUP
DEV_USER_PASS=DUP

### Preparations for calling jq
vars=$(cat<<EOF
{
 "ROOT_USER_PASS": "$ROOT_USER_PASS",
 "DEV_USER_PASS": "$DEV_USER_PASS"
}
EOF
)

cat << EOF | jq -nR --argfile template template.json --argjson vars "$vars" -f template.jq
$section0_section_uuid
$section1_section_uuid
EOF
```

#### Output

With the (expanded) example template, the output is:

```
{
  "fields": [],
  "sections": [
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "RUP",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME]"
        },
        {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "DUP",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME]"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Section_[CHANGE_ME]",
      "title": "Section_0"
    },
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "k": "string",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "placeholdertext",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME_LETTERS]"
        },
        {
          "k": "string",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "placeholdertext",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME_LETTERS]"
        },
        {
          "k": "concealed",
          "n": "[CHANGE_ME]",
          "t": "placeholdertext",
          "v": "[CHANGE_ME]"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Section_[CHANGE_ME]",
      "title": "Section_1"
    }
  ]
}
```